# real time clock using pic16lf1902/03

Tags: embedded, pic, i2c, microchip, lcd

I'm finding difficult in implementing real time clock for pic16lf1902, wherein their are no serial protocols for communicating/interfacing with builtin LCD drive. Is their a convenient way to solve the problem? For example using I2C software functions with DS1309 for LCD disply as used for PIC18 microcontrollers.

Comment: Explain this better. What has the RTC do to with your LCD? You have to read the RTC via SPI and write this to the display. If there are no driver to do this, write them (if you not already have)

Comment: @Miguel I want to implement real time clock and display it on LCD. I have already implemented it on pic16f877a using DS1307 with I2C, it works. But I'm not getting how to start with pic16lf1902.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong the DS1309 have already IIC. You must read your DS1309 via IIC, that should be nearly the same, maybee there are other registers to read. The configuration if the IIC-interface differs maybee a little, but procedure is the same- After that you must configure your LCD-Driver of the PIC, to display the values. You must read the datasheets of the PIC, the LCD and the clock to find out how to configure the registers in the microcontroller.

Comment: @Miguel That's fine! I will use similar procedure and try to interface DS1307 with LCD drive to display the time.

Comment: @VNegali: What IDE are you using? Your Hardware is already built? I have not used a PIC with LCD module, but IIC is simple, if you are are running it on the 16f it should be easy to implement this on the 16lf. The LCD may require little bit more reading and debugging.

Comment: @Miguel13366 I'm using MPLAB v8 with HI-TECH compiler and PROTEUS for simulation. This works with 16f but I can't find target device for 16lf on Proteus. I think I need to built a hardware. As 16lf comes with LCD driver, I'm bit confused how to access the registers and interface it using I2C.

Comment: @VNegali: Register addresses are in the headerfile for the controller. (Should come with MPLAB) Which registers to address is described in the Datasheet of PIC16LF1902/1903 (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001455D.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I2c can be implemented in software using any 2 IO port pins. Since I2C is a synchronous serial communication protocol software delays won't cause any problems. Here is the sample code for software I2C in 8051 micro controller.

http://www.8051projects.net/wiki/I2C_Implementation_on_8051

The same procedure can be followed in your case too.